Streamline Shader using Shader Nodes
I have created these streamlines in geometry nodes

Animation Here
However, I am limited as these streamlines are geometry and the vertices/polygons really start to add up.
There is a way to do streamlines in shaders like GLSL similar to those seen in this NASA video
https://youtu.be/CCmTY0PKGDs?si=cKDi96MtLW0M-Q5i
However, I have no idea how I would do this natively with Blenders shaders. Anyone wanna take a crack at it?
I have uploaded a vector field to test with. It is normalized around .5 being 0. So values less than .5 are negative and above are positive.


Do you know palette cycling? I think this would work if the streamlines aren't supposed to move.

Alternatively, you could convert your streamlines to grease pencil curves. I'm not sure but I think it could speed up if you have a lot of geometry.

@MarkusvonBroady It is animated.

@Lutzi. I just tried that (great idea!) but first attempt seems to fail. They become grease pencil lines except they are invisible. And I don't know how to make them visible. Not very familiar with grease pencils rendering system.

@TheJeran I've seen your animation,  but unlike in Nasa video,  your pathing seems to stay constant - no wonder: it's based on a static vector map.

I have tried with animating the vectormap but the temporal resolution this dataset isn't high enough. So there's a noticeable jump in the streamlines path when the frame switches to the next timestep. Actually, now that I think of it, I think I did download a 6-hourly dataset somewhere. Didn't try with that one.

Yea with the animated dataset my solution wouldn't work. Or rather, it would, but you would need to process all textures, which is reasonable for one but not so much for 6 hours (if you want the animation to play for 6 hours)

@TheJeran One idea would be : generate the streamlines in geometry nodes (as curves or as vertices&edges), then add a node to convert to grease pencil. I'm not really sure it would increase performances.

I just checked and dynamic paint brush will use its shape before geonodes are evaluated. So in order to use geonodes+dynamic paint, you would need to use python to parent a lot of small spheres into vertices that are then moved by geometry nodes. As for using shaders: a shader would need to have data on the distance on the path, in order to know what color to display for a given pixel. So you would need to do some processing on the vector texture.

@MarkusvonBroady Yea, to do this is GLSL you would need a buffer frame. I'm unsure how to do that in Blender. The streamlines in Geonodes are done with Simulation zones
